# Send a File from Server to API Using FormData

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I'm having issues formatting file data correctly so I can send it using an `XMLHttpRequest` with `FormData`.

This works fine on the front-end if I `append` the files directly from the form to `FormData`, but files kept on my server need to then be sent to an API, and I can't get this working no matter what I try. Please see the code below:

```
var filename = 'test123.txt';

// FormData
var FormData = require('form-data');

// Filereader
var FileAPI = require('file-api')
  , File = FileAPI.File
  , FileList = FileAPI.FileList
  , FileReader = FileAPI.FileReader
  ;
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.setNodeChunkedEncoding(true || false);
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(new File('server_path/filename'));

fileReader.on('data', function (resultData) {

    // New FormData
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('filename', resultData);

    // XHR
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xhr2").XMLHttpRequest;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "API_URL");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer API_TOKEN");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "undefined")
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({data}));

});
```

I've tried everything. Not using `JSON.stringify`, using other ways to read the file, sending all sorts of XHR headers, you name it.

If I output the result of `resultData`, I see `<Buffer 73 78 73 64 6a 61 20 64 6a 32 33 39 38 20 72 65 6a 38 39 77 65 20 72 38 39 33 6e 77 39 72 38 6e 33 77 39 38 72 6e 39 38 32 33 6e 38 39>`.

I admit that I'm not too sure what that means, so I imagine that I'm not reading enough data from the file possibly?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: I think you want to send the entire file and for that you want to listen for the 'load' event here. The 'data' event is for each read buffer and depending on whether the server can recieve file buffers may be the right way to go.

Comment: The code you posted is for NodeJS _or_ the Browser?

Comment: Also, are you _sure_ you need to send the data as `multipart/form-data`?